# Dimension of sumset

Tags: differential-geometry, sumset

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are $d$-dimensional set, subsets of $\mathbf{R}^N (N>>d)$

(More precisely, my case is : $X =Y= \{vec(xy^T)|x \in R^{d_1}, y \in R^{d_2}, \|x\|\leq 1, \|y\|\leq 1\}, N=d_1 d_2 $)

1. Can we say $Z=\{x+y| x \in X, y \in Y\}$ is a set of dimension less than $2d$? Or $Cd$ for some fixed constant C?
2. Can we generalize that argument for $X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_r$? (Something like...... it has dimension less than $rd$)

Please help!

Comment: If $X=Y$ subspace, then $X+Y=X$.

Comment: @Berci Sorry it is not a subspace.

Comment: Is the dimension of a set the dimension of the subspace it spans? Do you still want $Z$ to be a *subspace*?

Comment: @halrankard2 Nonono I edited that part, I don't want subspace condition.

Comment: And the first question, what is your definition of "dimension of a set"?

Comment: @halrankard2 What I exactly need is a packing dimension, but as long as I know, the usual dimension is bigger than the packing dimension so any definition of dimension would work...... You can even give conditions like X and Y are d-dimensional compact metric spaces.

Comment: @halrankard2 In fact, what I only need is the case I stated above.......

Comment: @halrankard2 packing dimension -> Hausdorff dimension